# Chrome/Firefox bug with my custom tag in head section - Not IE

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

My Head section is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Hi!</title>
    <mycustomtag att="1"></mycustomtag>
    <script>...</script>
    <!--anything else-->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The Chrome/Firefox problem is with MyCustomTag appearing in BODY section and the SCRIPT tag also. I don´t know why appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Hi!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <mycustomtag att="1"></mycustomtag>
    <script>...</script>
    <!--anything else-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any tag on the body section using chrome or firefox, I even used fiddle to check..it's all ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this problem is manage render of html and add custom marks to begin body and end body tags. This way can be delete all tags injected by browser. 
Chrome insert tags at the end of body also :s is incredible! The close tags are!
Thanks at all! –

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<style>
mycustomtag { display: none; }
</style>
```

The Chrome behavior is a feature, not a bug. When you use an invented tag, you deviate from HTML specifications, and browser may do whatever they want. (You also have a nonconforming doctype, which triggers quirks mode in some browsers.)

Comment: Thanks Jukka, but this don't resolve my problem. I need this tags not appear in the body section. When i call body.outerHTML this appear and the process in server side fail.

Comment: Do you need to use “custom” tags in HTML? They cause problems like this. Apparently the Chrome HTML parser treats the `<mycustomtag>` tag as implicitly closing the `head` element and opening the `body` element, since it is not one of the few tags allowed inside `head`.

Comment: The problem is that tag is a ASP.Net Control with runat="server" and this include functions and stylesheets. In one call the App in ASP.Net rendering Control like this why need it later.

Comment: If it does not work in any other browser, I would rather say that IE has a strange behavior. :P

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the issue that the element is in the `body` and not `head` in the DOM (as opposite to just the need to hide the element), manipulate the DOM by moving the element from `body` (if it is there) to `head`:

```
<script>
var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName('mycustomtag')[0];
if(myElement.parentNode === document.body) {
  document.body.removeChild(myElement);
  document.head.appendChild(myElement);
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jukka, but I don't have way to identify tags that are below this custom tag  to move.

Comment: I don’t see how that would matter. Is it not sufficient to move this element? The suggested code puts it at the end of `head`, but its placement inside the `head` should not matter.

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is manage render of html and add custom marks to begin body and end body tags. This way can be delete all tags injected by browser. Thanks at all!

Comment: Chrome insert tags at the end of body also :s is incredible! The close tags are!